# How to push the array of data to another array through javascript without loop

Tags: javascript

I have an Json array like data `{"alphaNumeric":[]}`.
Here I just want to push the another array `[mentioned below]` of objects to this *Data* with out loop concept.

```
data{"numeric":[{"id":"1","alpha":"a"},{"id":"2","alpha":"b"}]}.
```

I used the below code :
 `data.alphaNumeric.push(data.numeric);`

but the output is :

```
data{"alphaNumeric":[[{"id":"1","alpha":"a"},{"id":"2","alpha":"b"}]]}.
```

Expected :

```
data{"alphaNumeric":[{"id":"1","alpha":"a"},{"id":"2","alpha":"b"}]}.
```

Help me to resolve.

Comment: that's not an array, that's a javascript object. Can you please show *actual* code of what you're doing? Reduced to a minimal toy case is fine, but list code that people can run please.

Comment: .push() and .pop() are for adding and removing single elements in an array. The return value from .concat() is what you're looking for:
var newArr = oldArr.concat(extraArr);

Answer (score 3):

One solution may be using the `concat` method. Which isn't really good as it creates a whole new array.

```
b.alphaNumeric = b.alphaNumeric.concat(a.numeric);
```

But there is a much better solution using `push`. It accepts more than just one element, but unfortunately not as an array. This can be however achieved using its `apply` method:

```
b.alphaNumeric.push.apply(b.alphaNumeric, a.numeric);
```

Also you can write your own method (I call it `add`) which will do this action for you:

```
Array.prototype.add = function (array) {
  this.push.apply(this, array);
  return this;
};

b.alphaNumeric.add(a.numeric);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)**

```
data.alphaNumeric.concat(data.numeric);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.push()` and `.pop()` are for adding and removing single elements in an array. The return value from .concat() is what you're looking for:

```
var newArr = oldArr.concat(extraArr);
```