# Using array.prototype.push vs array.push

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I have seen people using two different ways of using different methods of the Array object in javascript.

I mostly use it like so:

```
arr.push(element1, ..., elementN)
```

But I have seen people using this:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(this,arguments)
```

I understand that all JavaScript objects inherit the properties and methods from their prototype. The Object.prototype is on the top of the prototype chain.

**What are the differences between two approaches and when should each approach be used?**

Comment: The latter is for stuff that isn't an array, like `arguments`.

Comment: `element1, ..., elementN` is a syntax error. `arguments` is not.

Comment: Pretty sure that was a placeholder ellipses.

Comment: Modifying the `arguments` object, especially by passing it out of the function to another function, is probably not the best idea in the world in general.

Comment: see [How to push the array of data to another array through javascript without loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24979471/1048572) for what it is good for.

Comment: @Pointy: `arguments` is not modifyied here?

Comment: @Bergi well adding an entry to it is what I meant; it's kind-of weird. Probably won't hurt anything however. *edit* oh wait I see. Right. Never mind :)

Comment: @Bergi The question cited as 'previously existing' has such a different title. Although by some luck it happens to have a related answer. How is the OP supposed to know such a different title would happen to have a answer for this question. To put it another way, just because some other question happens to have the same answer doesn't mean the two questions are the same.

Comment: "How to extend Array.prototype.push()?
 -> I'm trying to extend the Array.push method so that using push will trigger a callback method, then perform the normal array function." Its an unrelated question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The call via `.apply()` is used when you're interested in using `.push()` with an object that isn't really an array. A jQuery object, for example, is not really an array instance, but the code mostly maintains a `.length` property that's enough for it to *look like* an array, at least as far as `.push()` and other Array prototype methods are concerned.

For a real array instance, there's no need to do that; the `.push()` method is directly available via the prototype chain.

So:

```
var obj = { length: 0 };
Array.prototype.push.apply(obj, ["hello world"]);
console.log(obj[0]); // hello world
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Could you provide a little more explanation or an example of array.prototype.push being used in a scenario in pure javascript. I am currently staying away from jQuery I want to go through pure javascript first. I do understand what you have said but a very simple example/scenario would be extremely helpful. Again thank you so much.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn You *provided* an example of it being used in pure JS.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn jQuery is just JavaScript, and it's just an example. Any object that has a `.length` property that's an integer value will do.

Comment: @DaveNewton I was hoping for a very basic, nothing too fancy jsFiddle example. Something I can mess around with. And I can see it in action as how it worked.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn Copy what you have into a function in jsfiddle then call that function with arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you saw `Array.prototype.push.apply(this,arguments)` in an function like this

```
function foo() {
    arguments.push = function() {
       Array.prototype.push.apply(this,arguments);    
    } 
    arguments.push(1,2,3);
    //.... 
}
```

Here this is the foo's `arguments`, it is just an Array like object, not an Array, it does not have push method. So we should use `Array.prototype.push.apply(this,arguments)`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. could you explain what you mean by an "array like object"?

Comment: It doesn't matter that `arguments` doesn't have a push method? How do you think could one rewrite this code if it had?

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn Array-like objects look like arrays. They have various numbered elements and a length property. But that’s where the similarity stops. Array-like objects do not have any of Array’s functions, and for-in loops don’t even work! Check out these article:  http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/06/advanced-javascript-objects-arrays-and-array-like-objects/

Comment: @bcpeee But this is not what's happening. `arguments` is not the object that the `push` method is applied to. `this` is.

Comment: @basilikum You are right, so maybe `this` is not an Array in this case. Sorry I made a bad example, checkout the duplicated version question.